# PHP/SQL group content by year using timestamp

Tags: php, sql, json, date, object

I have a list of certificates that were issued in different years, I want to show the data in different container/div/group like

**Certificates issued in 2004:**

Title: German 102
Title: German 101

**Certificates issued in 2005:**

Title: German 201

**Certificates issued in 2006:**

Title: German 301

the DB object look something like this

```
Array (
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => German 101
            [issuedate] => 1072915200 //2004

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => German 102
            [issuedate] => 1092154787 //2004
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => German 201
            [issuedate] => 1104537600 //2005
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => German 301
            [issuedate] => 1136073600 //2006
        )

)
```

Edit: I could think of getting the timestamp at the beginning of the year from 2004 to 2044, but obviously this is not the best way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
echo date('Y', 1299446702);
```

And then sort using that.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array, and generate new array where key is year and value is array of your std objects:

```php
$newArray = [];
foreach ($yourArray as $std) {
    $newArray[date('Y', $std->issuedate)][] = $std;
}
ksort($newArray);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/618251)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

First question: Which database do you use?

Because most have a YEAR-function, that you're getting the number of each year, as separated column. With an `ORDER BY` date you can use in PHP something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($yourarray); $i++)
{
        $currentyear = $yourarray[$i]['year'];
        if($oldyear == $currentyear)
        {
            echo $yourarray[$i]['title'] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1>" . $currentyear . "<h1>" . $yourarray[$i]['title'] . "<br>";
        }

        $oldyear = $currentyear;
}
```